# Test script inside to postman on by get data for keep in variable?

Tags: postman

I need to store values from response data (below) in variable.

**Response Body:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "packages": [
            {
                "object": "AAA",
                "id": "BBB",
                "code": "123",
                "name": "Test8",
                "description": "Test111",
                "fee": "130.00 bath",
                "productSeq": "3"
            }, {
                "object": "AAA",
                "id": "CCC",
                "code": "456",
                "name": "Test9",
                "description": "Test222",
                "fee": "80.00 bath",
                "productSeq": "2"
            }, {
                "object": "AAA",
                "id": "CCC",
                "code": "789",
                "name": "Test10",
                "description":"Test111",
                "fee": "70.00 bath",
                "productSeq": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "resultCode": "20000",
    "resultDesc": "Success",
    "developerMessage": "Success"
}
```

If the `id` value of an object in the response is "CCC", I need to store that data like this, in a variable:

```
{
    "object": "AAA",
    "id": "CCC",
    "code": "456",
    "name": "Test9",
    "description": "Test222", 
    "fee": "80.00 bath",
    "productSeq": "2"
}, {
    "object": "AAA",
    "id": "CCC",
    "code": "789",
    "name": "Test10",
    "description":"Test111",
    "fee": "70.00 bath",
    "productSeq": "1"
}
```

Can you help me create the script that would do that?

Comment: Sorry i beginer post question
Thank you for edit format

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: -

```html
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody)
var objArray = [];
for (i=0; i<body.data.packages.length;i++){
   if (body.data.packages[i].id === "CCC"){
      objArray.push(body.data.packages[i]);
   }
}
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("varName", objArray)
```

Comment: i run postman display as below
varName = [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: You should use JSON.stringify() before setting it to environment variable.

Then after you call it in next request, use JSON.parse() to recreate the object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can not get "," in response msg 
i should get ',' how to work?